# Global name 'row' is not defined

Tags: python, crud

Here's my code...I am getting

```
    .format(table_name=self._table, condition=row['where']))
NameError: global name 'row' is not defined
```

Code:

```
def retrieveSmCityCust(self, key):
    cursor = self._db.execute('SELECT CONTRACTS.CUSTOMER_NAME, CONTRACTS.CUSTOMER.CITY, CITIES.POPULATION FROM CONTRACTS JOIN CITIES ON CONTRACTS.CUSTOMER_CITY = CITIES.IDENT where {condition}'.format(table_name=self._table, condition=row['where']))
    return dict(cursor.fetchall())

db = database(filename = 'insurance.sqlite')

db.retrieveSmCityCust({'where': 'CITIES.POPULATION <=500000'})
    for row in db:
        print(row)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where *is* `row` defined?

Comment: condition=row['where'] ??? I swear this is my first python application...

Comment: @Martijn's got it. I was still formatting your code in my editor so that I could see it!

Comment: Also, you're not using `table_name` in your `format()` call.

Comment: sorry, I had a typo def retrieveSmCityCust(self, key) should be def retrieveSmCityCust(self, row):

Comment: It would help if you pasted actual code, rather than reconstructing it. It would also help if you kept your lines under 80 characters.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: The `.format()` method doesn't care if you pass in extra keywords that are not used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I understand that :)

Comment: @user2096860: So, in summary, my answer is correct then? Or are you *still* getting that error even though you corrected `key` to `row`?

Comment: how can I print only these columns in the result? SELECT CONTRACTS.CUSTOMER_NAME, CONTRACTS.CUSTOMER_CITY, CITIES.POPULATION

Comment: @user2096860: the result already is going to be rows of three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your function parameter `key`, not `row`. Use `key['where']` instead, or rename the parameter to the function to `row`.